# acces to a subclass variable in arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to access the method `getDimensioni` of an element of a subclass of `Campo` called `Calcio`.

Here's the code where I want to do it:

```
ArrayList<Campo> campiprenotati = new ArrayList<>();

public void prenotazioniCC7(){
    for (Calcio calcio : campiprenotati) {
        if("7".equals(calcio.getDimensioni())) { 
            System.out.println(calcio.tostring());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Campo non trovato");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's `Calcio.java`:

```
public class Calcio extends Campo {
    private String dimensioni;

    public Calcio(String ID, boolean illuminazione, String dimensioni) {
        super(ID, illuminazione);
        this.dimensioni = dimensioni;
    }

    public void setDimensioni() {
        this.dimensioni = dimensioni;
    }

    public String getDimensioni() {
        return dimensioni;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " " + dimensioni;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code for `Campo` and `Calcio`.

Comment: When asking for help, it's best to format your code in a consistent, clear, and at least somewhat standard way. (It's best when not asking for help, too.) I've formatted your code for you on this occasion.

Comment: (And whoever it is that's teaching people to put `}` at the end of the last statement of a block (it's not just the OP, I've seen several different people do it) is doing them and the rest of us a **massive** disservice. It's hard to read, hard to edit, easy to overlook errors in, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `ArrayList` is of `Campo` elements, you can't know that only contains `Calcio` elements (it may have elements of type `Campo` or other subclasses), so you can't use `Calcio` for your `for` loop element type. You *could* use `Campo` and then use `instanceof` to find out if the `Campo` is a `Calcio`, like this:

```
public void prenotazioniCC7(){
    for (Campo campo : campiprenotati) {
// ------^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (campo instanceof Calcio && "7".equals(((Calcio)campo).getDimensioni())) { 
// ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            System.out.println(campo.toString());
// ----------------------------^^^^^
        } else {
            System.out.println("Campo non trovato");
        }
    }
}
```

**but** using `instanceof` generally (though not always) suggests that you may want to structure things differently, for instance by making the array only contain `Calcio` elements.

For instance, oOne approach (as suggested by [TungstenX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537566/tungstenx) in the comments), would be to identify all the common aspects of the elements that need to be in this list (and lists like it) and put them in an interface that all of the relevant classes implement:

```
public class Campo /*...*/

public interface TheInterface {
    String getDimensioni();
}

public class Calcio extends Campo implements TheInterface /*...*/
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- only if necessary and appropriate
```

then

```
ArrayList<TheInterface> campiprenotati = new ArrayList<>();

public void prenotazioniCC7(){
    for (TheInterface entry : campiprenotati) {
        if ("7".equals(entry.getDimensioni())) { 
            System.out.println(entry.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Campo non trovato");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless Campo is an interface that Calcio extends?

Comment: @TungstenX he could refactor the code so that `Campo` is an interface, but in the current code that's not the case. Also, the `getDimenzioni()` method is class-specific, it's not part of the superclass.

Comment: thanks a lot. i don't know why but i swear you a i've tried to do this but always the code give me error with istanceof  line...and i'm noticing only now that is INSTANCEOF and not istance...sorry for my blindness and thanks again :)

Comment: @DarioBirtone - Glad that helped! See also TungstenX's point above: If you can extract the common things about the objects that will be in this list into an interface, and have all of the classes implement that interface, then you can use `ArrayList<TheInterface>` and `for (TheInterface entry : campiprenotati)`.

Comment: @TungstenX - Very good point, I've added that approach to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> it depends how are calling in your use case and where you are creating this list, inject your list object in your base class using constructor and use in methods, if your list is creating at run time you can inject this list in constructor.

```
ArrayList<Campo> campiprenotati;

public MyClass(final ArrayList<Campo> campiprenotati){
    this.campiprenotati = campiprenotati;
}
```

> Now you can create and pass list object of subclass and use it, but still it is not good design of your code.